# Solution for form tag without action attribute in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2

How to write a form tag without action attribute in Struts2?

```
s:form name="OptionsForm" method="POST"
```

the above is working but it shows

> No configuration found for the specified action: '/Options.jsp' in namespace: ''. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action attribute is not required for the [`s:form`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/form.html) tag.

The current action will be used by default. If the page is rendered by not the action then to this JSP page.

You can use a JavaScript framework to modify DOM for the form element and add the `action` attribute before the form is submitted.